# Assigning a Public IP for RaspberryPi in local area wired network

Tags: raspberry-pi, networking, network-interface

We are trying to configure RaspberryPi with public IP (192.248.10.71) in local area wired network.

This is the network configuration in /etc/network/interfaces,

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
#iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.248.10.71
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.8.159.254
broadcast 192.248.10.255
network 192.248.10.0
nameserver 192.248.8.97

#allow-hotplug wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet manual
#wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#iface default inet dhcp
```

We have also configured a Ubuntu server with public IP (192.248.10.70) in same local area network with above configuration. (But using graphical interface)

I could ping & ssh from Ubuntu server to RaspberryPi. But I couldn't ping or ssh from a computer in same local area network. I also couldn't ping for even google from RaspberryPi. I also couldn't ping for the gateway or nameserver from RaspberryPi. But I could do everything from Ubuntu server.

**Updated :**

Ubuntu server configurations,

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1d:09:2a:49:13  
      inet addr:192.248.10.70  Bcast:192.248.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::21d:9ff:fe2a:4913/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7145615 errors:0 dropped:10724 overruns:0 frame:1
      TX packets:1578727 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:730033760 (730.0 MB)  TX bytes:301369151 (301.3 MB)
      Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:353553 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:353553 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:37882267 (37.8 MB)  TX bytes:37882267 (37.8 MB)
```

System configuration (As we did in graphical interfaces)

```
[802-3-ethernet]
duplex=full
mac-address=00:1D:09:2A:49:13

[connection]
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=3a373445-9cc1-4852-a9de-959647668b76
type=802-3-ethernet
timestamp=1420442035

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=manual
dns=192.248.8.97;
address1=192.248.10.70/24,10.8.159.254
```

Ping for gateway to Ubuntu server works.

Trace route output for Ubuntu server(192.248.10.70) to gateway(10.8.159.254)

```
 traceroute to 10.8.159.254 (10.8.159.254), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
  1  10.8.159.254 (10.8.159.254)  2.253 ms * *
```

Any help from experience people is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It reads like you have mixed up some coulds and couldn'ts there - please clarify them.  Also, get a basic understanding of how IP networks operate and try again.

Comment: Ya Sorry. Edited.

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design!

Comment: Consider http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/...

Answer (score 4):

In an IP network a computer is only able to directly talk to another computer or device on its own subnet.  That subnet is defined by the netmask.

So your subnet for the IP address 192.248.10.71, which has a netmask of 255.255.255.0, has a range of 192.248.10.0 to 192.248.10.255.

So the only computers the Pi can talk to have to have an IP address in that range - which of course includes the Ubuntu computer.

Any other computers have to be talked to via a gateway.  Gateways have to exist on both the subnet your device is on and on the subnet that the target device is on - or on a subnet which itself has a gateway that leads, eventually, to the device in question.

Your Pi cannot talk to the gateway 10.8.159.254 because it is not on the same subnet.  Because it can't talk to that gateway it can't talk to anything else through that gateway, such as Google, your name servers, etc.

Comment: Then do we have to set netmask 0.0.0.0?

Comment: No. You won't get any routing at all then.  The Pi has to be physically in the same subnet as a gateway in the IP range 192.248.10.0 to 192.248.10.255.

Comment: But ubuntu server(192.248.10.70) is work fine with same gateway and netmask configurations. How would it happens?

Comment: It can't be working as you think it's working. Do you by chance have two IP addresses set up on the Ubuntu server?

Comment: Or do you mean that it can talk to the Pi? It can do that because they are both in the same subnet.

Comment: I have updated Ubuntu server configurations

Comment: Which do you actually mean by "works"? Can ping the internet, or can ping the Pi?

Comment: yes. I could ping for Internet and for Pi. As you mentioned is there two IP configured. Public and private?

Comment: I thought there was but misread the configuration.  If course, there may be an ipv6 network running at your university as well, and it's actually that you're accessing the internet through? Unlikely though. But still, unless there is a second IP on the Ubuntu machine it cannot directly communicate with the gateway as stated, so something must be set that you're not showing us. Ping the gateway. Better still, do a traceroute to the gateway.

Comment: I have updated traceroute and ping details.

Comment: The only way you can get that traceroute result is if your Ubuntu computer is directly connected to the 10.whatever subnet. There has to be a second IP address either on an alias interface (eth0:0?) or on a second ethernet or wireless interface.